# Acer Aspire ES1-111 LUBUNTU WiFI

Tags: wireless

Despite finding so many articles, in highly technical jargon, I cannot get the laptop to find any way of connecting to Wi-Fi.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Please, make mention of the Operating System you're using, including its version. For example, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Found  [this](https://gist.github.com/glombard/18a7ea331cfc93aff17b) ... and managed to sort it...

```
# Determine wireless device model (manufacturer 14e4 for Broadcom):
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

# Install Broadcom STA driver for BCM43227: 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl

# Connect (press Fn+F3 to enable wifi if necessary first):
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid MYSSID key s:MyWifiPwd
sudo dhclient wlan0

# Troubleshooting commands:
iwconfig
nm-tool
rfkill list
sudo lshw -C network
```